# ANTLR 4: Recognises 'and' but not 'or' without a space

Tags: antlr4

I'm using the ANTLR 4 plugin in IntelliJ, and I have the most bizarre bug. I'll start with the relevant parser/lexer rules:

```
// Take care of whitespace.
WS : [ \r\t\f\n]+ -> skip;

OTHER: . -> skip;

STRING
: '"' [A-z ]+ '"'
;

evaluate // starting rule.
: textbox? // could be an empty textbox.
;

textbox
: (row '\n')*
;

row
: ability
| ability_list

ability
: activated_ability
| triggered_ability
| static_ability

triggered_ability
: trigger_words ',' STRING 
;

trigger_words
: ('when'|'whenever'|'as') whenever_triggers|'at'
;

whenever_triggers
: triggerer (('or'|'and') triggerer)* // this line has the issue.
;

triggerer
: self

self: '~'
```

I pass it this text: `whenever ~ or ~`, and it fails on the `or`, saying `line 1:10 mismatched input ' or' expecting {'or', 'and'}`. However, if I add a space to the `whenever_triggers` rule's `or` string (making it `' or'|'and'`), it works fine.

The weirdest thing is that if I try `whenever ~ and ~`, it works fine even without the rule having a space in the `and` string. This doesn't change if I make `'and'|'or'` a lexer rule either. It's just bizarre. I've confirmed this bug happens when running the 'test rig' in Antlrworks 2, so it's not just an IntelliJ thing.

This is an image of the parse tree when the error occurs:

[image]

Comment: Your `STRING` rule won' t be matched because the input will always be considered to belong to `OTHER` before even checking for the `STRING`-rule. And I'm not sure about the implicit lexer definitions in your grammar and how they might interfere with the `OTHER` rule... Try to put it at the end of the grammar and see if that changes anything

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/antlr/3271/lexer-rules-in-v4/11235/priority-rules#t=201704141056079647247

Comment: @Raven I put the OTHER rule at the end and even removed it, it didn't change anything. The STRING rule was just a placeholder I made, it doesn't even come into play for my example.

LucasTrzesniewski I read through the docs but didn't see anything regarding spaces/whitespace that helps my issue.

Comment: Yes it does... You want to match `\n` as `WS` but you have an implicit lexer declaration in the rule `textbox` so it will match as that... Therefore you are getting the error about the newline in  `triggered_ability` and I assume that this is causing the rest to go wrong as well

Comment: If that's the case, why does `and` work fine, while `or` does not? I shrunk my whitespace rule to `WS : [ \r\t]+ -> skip;` but that doesn't change anything either.

Comment: @Raven So I found a partial solution; another one of my rules had `(' or'|'and')` in it, when I changed that to `'or'` it solved my problem. However I'm still confused as to why that occurred, which will probably mean that I make this mistake again...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright you have found the answer more or less by yourself so with this answer of mine I will focus on explaining why the problem occured in the first place.

First of all - for everyone stumbling upon this question - the problem was that he had another implicit lexer rule defined that looked like this `' or'` (notice the whitespace). Changing that to `'or'` resolved the problem.

But why was that a problem?
In order to understand that you have to understand what ANTLR does if you write `'<something>'` in one of your parser rules: When compiling the grammar it will generate a new lexer rule for each of those declarations. These lexer rules will be created before the lexer rules defined in your grammar. The lexer itself will match the given input into tokens and for that it processes each lexer rule at a time in the order they have been declared. Therefore it will always start with the implicit token definitions and then move on to the topmost "real" lexer rule.
The problem is that the lexer isn't too clever about this process that means once it has matched some input with the current lexer rule it will create a respective token and moves on with the trailing input.

As a result a lexer rule that comes afterwards that would have matched the input as well (but as another token as it is a different lexer rule) will be skipped so that the respective input might not have the expected token type because the lexer rules have overwrritten themselves.

In your example the self-overwriting rules are `' or'`(Token 1) and `'or'`(Token 2). Each of those implicit lexer rule declarations will result in a different lexer rule and as the first one got matched I assume that it is declared before the second one.
Now look at your input: `whenever ~ or ~` The lexer will start interpreting it and the first rule it comes across is `' or'` (After the start is matched of course) and it will match the input as there really is a space before the `or`. Therefore it will match it as Token 1.
The parser on the other hand is expecting a Token 2 at this point so that it will complain about the given input (although it really is complaining about the wrong token type). Altering the input to `whenever ~or ~` will result in the correct interpretation.

Exactly that is the reason why you shouldn't use implicit token definitions in your grammar (unless it is really small). Create a new lexer rule for every input and start with the most specific rules. That means rules that match special character sequences (e.g. keywords) should be declared before general lexer rules like `ID` or `STRING` or something like that. Rules that will match all the characters in order to prevent the lexer from throwing an error upon unrecognized input have to declared last as they would overwrite every lexer rule after them.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation, it's definitely helping me understand. My plan now is to create a single lexer rule for each string I need to use (e.g. `OR: 'or';` and then use those lexers in other lexer/parser rules so that I don't get these sort of mixups again; is that generally the right approach?

Comment: Yes it is. It will also help you to prevent typos ;)